# How to send form data using Ajax+JQuery in form of JSON object to spring restful web services API?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring, rest

I am try to send JSON object data using Ajax+JQuery to send the **Spring Restful web services**, But It is not sending the data on eclipse console I am getting following message in eclipse console.

**Message in eclipse:**

```
 16:47:36.293 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing POST request for [/HomeServiceProvider/customer/saveCustomer]
    16:47:36.293 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /customer/saveCustomer
    16:47:36.295 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported
    16:47:36.295 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported
    16:47:36.295 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported
    16:47:36.295 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
    16:47:36.295 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

**My form.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
<meta header="application/json">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
  alert("1");
  var customer = new Object();
    customer.custName = $('#custName').val();
    customer.custMobile = $('#custMobile').val();
    customer.custEmail = $('#custEmail').val();
    customer.custAddress = $('#custAddress').val();
    alert("2"); 
                 $.ajax({
                     url: 'http://localhost:8080/HomeServiceProvider/customer/saveCustomer',
                     type: 'POST',
                     dataType: 'json',
                     data: customer,
                     success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                         console.log(data);
                     },
                     error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                         console.log('Error in Operation');
                     }
                 });
                 alert("3");
  });
  alert("3");
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    <fieldset style="text-align:right; width:300px">
    <legend><b>Registration Form</b></legend>
        Name <input type="text" id="custName" name="custName"/><br/>
        Mobile No <input type="text" id="custMobile" name="custMobile"/><br/>
        Email <input type="text" id="custEmail" name="custEmail"/><br/>
        Address <input type="text" id="custAddress" name="custAddress"/><br/>       
        <button id="button">Save Data</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CustomerRestController.java**

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/customer")
    public class CustomerRestController {

        private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(CustomerRestController.class);

        @Value("${msg.customeradded}")
        private String message;
        @Value("${msg.successcode}")
        private int code;

        @Autowired
        private CustomerService customerService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/saveCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json") 
        public @ResponseBody Status saveCustomer(@RequestBody String jsonString){
        //check whether u r receiving some data over here 
        System.out.println("received :" + jsonString);
            try { 
               // customerService.saveCustomer(customer); 
                return new Status(code, message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return new Status(0, e.toString());
            } 
        } 

        @RequestMapping(value="/getAllCustomer",method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
        public @ResponseBody List<Customer> getAllCustomer(){
            List<Customer> customers = null;
            try {
                customers = customerService.getAllCustomer();
            log.info("Size:"+customers.size());
            log.info("customers:"+customers);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return customers;
        }
    }
```

**Customer.Java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer", catalog = "service4homes")
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer CId;
    private String custName;
    private String custMobile;
    private String custEmail;
    private String custAddress;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String custName, String custMobile, String custAddress) {
        this.custName = custName;
        this.custMobile = custMobile;
        this.custAddress = custAddress;
    }

    public Customer(String custName, String custMobile, String custEmail,
            String custAddress) {
        this.custName = custName;
        this.custMobile = custMobile;
        this.custEmail = custEmail;
        this.custAddress = custAddress;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "c_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getCId() {
        return this.CId;
    }

    public void setCId(Integer CId) {
        this.CId = CId;
    }

    @Column(name = "cust_name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getCustName() {
        return this.custName;
    }

    public void setCustName(String custName) {
        this.custName = custName;
    }

    @Column(name = "cust_mobile", nullable = false, length = 13)
    public String getCustMobile() {
        return this.custMobile;
    }

    public void setCustMobile(String custMobile) {
        this.custMobile = custMobile;
    }

    @Column(name = "cust_email", length = 100)
    public String getCustEmail() {
        return this.custEmail;
    }

    public void setCustEmail(String custEmail) {
        this.custEmail = custEmail;
    }

    @Column(name = "cust_address", nullable = false, length = 300)
    public String getCustAddress() {
        return this.custAddress;
    }

    public void setCustAddress(String custAddress) {
        this.custAddress = custAddress;
    }

}
```

Comment: have you fixed you issue?